# Don't understand why my SQL isn't working

Tags: sql, oracle

```
/* DROP TABLE STATEMENTS*/
DROP TABLE BUILDING CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE ROOM CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE CONFERENCESESSION CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE SPEAKER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;

/* CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS*/
CREATE TABLE BUILDING(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
BUILDINGWING VARCHAR2(15),
BUILDINGLANE VARCHAR2(15),
CONSTRAINT BUILDING_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO));

CREATE TABLE ROOM(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
ROOMCAPACITY NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO));

CREATE TABLE SPEAKER(
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SPEAKERNAME VARCHAR2(20),
SPEAKERADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
SPEAKERPHONE CHAR(12),
CONSTRAINT SPEAKER_PK PRIMARY KEY(SPEAKERID));

CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION(
SESSIONID CHAR(4),
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4, 2),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO)REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID));
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I get this error when running the above code:

> Table BUILDING dropped.
>
> Table ROOM dropped.
>
> Error starting at line : 4 in command -
>   DROP TABLE CONFERENCESESSION CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE
>   Error report -
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>
> Table SPEAKER dropped.
>
> Table BUILDING created.
>
> Table ROOM created.
>
> Table SPEAKER created.
>
> Error starting at line : 28 in command -
>   CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION(
>   SESSIONID CHAR(4),
>   BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
>   ROOMNO CHAR(2),
>   SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
>   SESSIONDATE DATE,
>   SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4, 2),
>   CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
>   CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO)REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
>   CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO),
>   CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID))
>
> Error report -
>   ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>   *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
>   *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO)`: A foreign key has to reference the *entire* primary key (or unique key) of another table. So simply add buildingno:

```
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO)
```